# Why I can't download png format file using SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am trying to debug my code, and I find out that the problem why my image doesn't appear because  somehow I can't download my png format file using SDWebImage.

if the format is jpg it can work properly. here is the full simplified code in the table view controller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var imageURLs = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        imageURLs = ["https://app10.pakubuwono6.com/hris/images/notification/Logo Small.png", "https://app10.pakubuwono6.com/hris/images/notification/Logo Small.png", "https://app10.pakubuwono6.com/hris/images/notification/Logo Small.png", "https://app10.pakubuwono6.com/hris/images/notification/Logo Small.png"]
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageURLs.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellImage") as! CellImage
        cell.imageExample.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURLs[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload])
        return cell
    }
}
```

I am using the line of code below to download  the image, I set the image in the table view cell in this view controller

```
cell.imageExample.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURLs[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload])
```

what went wrong in here?

just appear the placeholder image
[image]

Comment: Chck your Image url in browser either image is available or not.

Comment: Use https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher, best library for iOS

Comment: The space between the file name is ignored because of the % encoding by the SDWebimage. Please follow the addingPercentEncoding as mentioned by the @DuncanC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image url include white space
try this code

```
if let url = imageURLs[indexPath.row].addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed){
 cell.imageExample.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload])

}
```

Comment: Percent-encoding the entire URL is a bad idea because the structural parts of the URL (the `://`, the `&`, the `=`, etc) should not be escaped, but any fields that contain those characters should be escaped (so if a query parameter contains a `=` sign or a `&` it should be escaped, for example, but the `=` and `&` characters that mark the query fields should **not** be escaped.

Comment: i'm using urlQueryAllowed  the encoding of the query just 

see this 
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset

Answer (score 3):

You don't show the `setImage(with:placeholderImage:options:)` method you are using to load the image, so it's a bit hard to tell what exactly is going on.

An obvious problem, though, is that your image URLS contain un-escaped spaces. You should change your URLs like this:

```
imageURLs = 
  ["https://app10.pakubuwono6.com/hris/images/notification/Logo%20Small.png", 
  "https://app10.pakubuwono6.com/hris/images/notification/Logo%20Small.png", 
  "https://app10.pakubuwono6.com/hris/images/notification/Logo%20Small.png", 
  "https://app10.pakubuwono6.com/hris/images/notification/Logo%20Small.png"]
```

(Note that you can't use `addingPercentEncoding` on the entire URL string as suggested in th other answer because the other symbols in the URL string should not be escaped, just the filename. )

It's really better to build URLs using `URLComponents`. You specify the different parts of the URL and then ask `URLComponents` to give you a URL. It escapes the different components correctly for you.